# What might be a strategy to detect a retain cycle in an object hierarchy programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, retaincount, retain-cycle

I'm writing an ARC-enabled framework which creates a hierarchy of objects, not unlike Cocoa's view hierarchy. Each controller object can have several subcontrollers. Controllers may have references to each other, which poses the potential risk of creating a retain cycle.

**I know how to avoid retain cycles. I want to know if there's a way for me to detect programmatically that a retain cycle exists and prevents an object from deallocating?**

At some point, the existing root controller will be replaced by a new root controller. Since I'm using ARC I can't use retainCount to check the existing controller's retain count. Which is not to be trusted anyway from what I've read.

I have a test setup where the root controller has two sub controllers, and each of them has a strong reference to the other. In that case the root controller does not run dealloc, neither do the other two controllers when the root controller is replaced with a new controller. As expected. I was thinking that given this scenario, there should be some way for me to determine whether that root controller did actually deallocate or not.

**Possible Solution:** I did assign the to-be-replaced root controller to a zeroing weak property on a global object shortly before replacing the controller. Then I have setup a timer so that after a fraction of a second I check if the property is nil or not. If it's nil, the controller did deallocate. If it's not nil, it probably indicates a memory leak likely to have been caused by a retain cycle somewhere in the hierarchy. In that case I print a log statement for as long as the replaced controller is not nil to get the developer's attention.

This works, but are there any alternative (better) solutions? Or possible caveats with this solution?

Specifically, how much time can pass before the object deallocates - is this guaranteed to be instantaneous or can deallocation be delayed and if so, for how long?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm writing an ARC-enabled framework which creates a hierarchy of objects, not unlike Cocoa's view hierarchy…

Stop right there. Just introduce that relationship into your hierarchy. Views have parents, subviews, etc. -- consider how they interact and keep each other alive for appropriate lengths. Teach your objects about the relations they need, and teach them how to clean up after themselves. Simplified:

```
- (void)tearDownState
{
  if (self.isTearingDown)
    return;

  [self setTearingDown];
  for (Node * at in self.subnodes) {
    [at tearDownState];
  }
  self.subnodes = 0;
  ...
```

then if you also need to exchange nodes (e.g. your root), teach them to exchange nodes.

Comment: I'm concerned about user code. A user could write subclasses of nodes, let's call them A and B. In A, he assigns a strong reference to B, In B, he does the same thing and has a strong reference to A. There's nothing I can do to prevent that or clean that up in my framework because I have no knowledge of that connection. But if I understand you correctly, you're saying I should add some way to share nodes (ie array/dict of "friend nodes" in each node) so the user doesn't have to create that manual connection? But what if he does anyway?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D a) views may also be subclassed. views may also be referenced outside their graph b) right, just like views hold strong references to their subviews. when the client does a poor job of maintaining those strong references, then leaks and circular references may be introduced -- just like in view controllers (which introduce additional steps for constructing and destructing their state conveniently). that should be common knowledge for cocoa devs -- you shouldn't have to implement a garbage collector. (cont)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D another option would be to simply abstract the nodes from the client entirely, so they don't even know of the nodes' existence. then you could eliminate the possibility of them referencing or deriving from the nodes.

Comment: All I want is to inform the user when the hierarchy doesn't deallocate. The big problem with that is that it's so easy to miss, and ignore. And may cause the strangest bugs. Detecting a retain cycle early is crucial, if the framework can do the detection (*not* the cleanup!) then I'm happy. Right now, the weak property + timer solution seems to work well.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D ok well i'm really not sure what to tell you other than well defined semantics and error detection is opt in. you'll need to write some stronger, more deterministic programs to prove existence of the bug, as well as a good amount of foresight and understanding of how your users will or may use the program to complement and reinforce that. these details just aren't in the OP. without knowing the context your program is intended to run in, it is sufficient to say that your proposed solution is capable of false positives and negatives; even your (cont)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D (cont) comment *"If it's not nil, it **probably** indicates a memory leak…"* suggests you are already aware of this deficiency in the solution you proposed. regardless of that, the system would impose many odd constraints on your library's users if that proposal were forced to be adequate and provide 100% accuracy. ultimately, i fail to see why such constraints are preferable to introducing structure, determinism, and well defined semantics. false positives and negatives are bugs in their own right.